# How to create charts in iOS app like this?

Tags: ios, swift, charts

[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSJix.jpg)
How create create charts in iOS app like this?

Comment: check this: https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this pod:
https://cocoapods.org/pods/Charts
its simple, and efficient